# Composite key joins in hibernate in java

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate to persist two tables,`Project` and `Department`.

`Department` table has a composite primary key `DeptCompID`.

```
    @Embeddable
    public class DeptCompID implements Serializable
    {

        @Column(name = "DeptID")
        private int DeptID;

        @Column(name = "RoleID")
        private int RoleID;

        //getters and setters
    }

@Entity
public class Department implements Serializable
{

    @EmbeddedId 
    private DeptCompID id;

     private String name;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="department",targetEntity = Project.class)
    private Project pro;

    //getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Project 

{
    @Id
    private int ProId;


    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Department.class)
    @MapsId("DeptID")
    @JoinColumns({    
    @JoinColumn(name = "RoleID", referencedColumnName = "RoleID"),
    @JoinColumn(name = "DeptID", referencedColumnName = "DeptID")
    })
     private Department department;

//getters and setters
}
```

**Code to persist the tables**

```
            Department department = new Department();
            department.setName("HR");
            DeptCompID cpk=new DeptCompID();
            cpk.setRoleID(10);
            cpk.setDeptID(60);
            department.setId(cpk);

            Project pro=new Project();
            pro.setDepartment(department);
            pro.setProId(10);
            department.setPro(pro);
            session.save(department);
            session.save(pro);
```

Everytime I persist the tables Project and Department the `DeptID` column in `Project` table is always null when it should be 60.
why is `@MapsId("DeptID")` not working?Could some provide a resolution.